# How to render html template in javascript template in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have 2 files, `create.js.eex` and `post.html.eex` and I want to render the contents of the `post.html.eex` template inside the `create.js.eex` template. Something like this:

```
$("#something").append("<%= safe_to_string render "post.html", post: @post %>");
```

The example above doesn't work because I need to escape quotes and other things in the string that gets returned and I can't find a way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use escape_javascript:

```
$("#something").append("<%= escape_javascript render("post.html", post: @post) %>");
```

You can render_to_string and escape that, but there doesn't seem to be much need -- and since it returns a string, it will HTML-escape all the markup.

Actually, this exact example is in the docs:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#escape_javascript/1

Comment: Haha I actually PRed that function

Answer (score 6):

You can use `render_to_string`

```
    Phoenix.View.render_to_string(MyApp.PageView, "index.html", foo: "bar")
```

Be aware that this can expose you to XSS.